# Get difference of remote and local branch

Tags: git, compare, branch, diff, git-remote

I've created a **remote branch (dev_admin)** which one can see by running the command **'git remote -v'**. Another default branch is on my **local (master)** which one can view by running the command **'git branch'**. I want to get the **difference** of these two branches '**dev_admin**' and '**master**'.

I've tried the following git commands from git documentations as well as from the answers from the very same platform 'stackoverflow':

`git diff --compact-summary --ignore-space-change dev_admin master`

`gitk --left-right remotes/dev_admin...master`

I've tried one or two other commands too, but none of them worked. And i'm stuck here. Can anyone help me with this, so that i could get a difference between these two branches..??

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be confusing *remotes* and *remote branches*. What's `dev_admin`? A remote branch or a remote? Can't be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you find the branch in `git branch --all`?

If you can, maybe `git diff [branch1] [branch2]` will take effect.

Comment: Thanks buddy, git branch --all helped me to get all the branch names and my 1st command worked, when i ran the command with the full names of the branches.